# How to make HttpClient use Kerberos?

Tags: java, kerberos, apache-commons-httpclient

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) is a Java library to browse websites.
I want to use it with [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29). The [Kerberos part of HttpClient's documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d5e1094) mostly says:

> The best way to start is to grab the KerberosHttpClient.java file in examples and try and get it to work.

However, `KerberosHttpClient.java` is nowhere to be found ([source](http://ftp.meisei-u.ac.jp/mirror/apache/dist//httpcomponents/httpclient/source/httpcomponents-client-4.2-src.tar.gz), [binaries](http://ftp.meisei-u.ac.jp/mirror/apache/dist//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.2-bin.tar.gz), [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html))
It is difficult to do anything without this file.

Where can I find `KerberosHttpClient.java`?
Or is there a better document explaining how to use HttpClient with Kerberos?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [sources](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) you will find the file `ClientKerberosAuthentication.java` with that example.

```
httpcomponents-client-4.2/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientKerberosAuthentication.java
```

By the way, setting up Kerberos authentication requires many steps at KDC side (ActiveDirectory I guess) and HTTP server side too. I recommend you this [generic server setup documentation](http://grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/) even if targeting mod_auth_kerb, it addresses concepts and troubleshooting required to achieve the job.

Comment: [Here's a link to ClientKerberosAuthentication.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.2.2/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientKerberosAuthentication.java) in SVN

Comment: The sample seems to be missing for the latest version 4.3.3. Anyone?

Comment: @Andy, It's certainly because DefaultHttpClient used in the [ClientKerberosAuthentication](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.2.2/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientKerberosAuthentication.java) has been deprecated in version 4.3, and no new example was provided

Comment: You may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629132/httpclient-set-credentials-for-kerberos-authentication